# Having dataset in another folder

Tags: c#, winforms, filepath

I have the Windows Form Application which works with 2 data sets(text files). How can change the path of text files from `C Drive` into the `Documents folder` with following adress: Libraries\Documents? 
If I want copy them into the desktop what can be the path?
PS: I copy the data sets into Documents and change the

```
StreamReader fileitem = new StreamReader("c:\\dataset.txt");\
```

into:

```
StreamReader fileitem = new StreamReader("Libraries\Documents\dataset.txt");
```

But it doesnot work.

An idea?

Comment: "Libraries" is not a real folder. It's a virtual folder that "combines" other folders into one group. So you can't use that in path names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `Environment.GetFolderPath`.

```
string myDocuments = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

Don't concatenate strings to create path, use `Path.Combine` instead. So when you need subfolder of desktop you'll use

```
string subFolder = Path.Combine(desktop,"MySubFolderName");
```

So in your case

```
StreamReader fileitem = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(desktop,"dataset.txt"));
```

Comment: you @SriramSakthivel mean, i must do like:                             string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);     StreamReader fileitem = new StreamReader(my Documents+"dataset.txt");

Comment: @user3403967 Updated answer to your requirements

Comment: thanks for your answer @SriramSakthivel. If I want to change the path the exe path of application. I mean I copy the text files into the .../bin/debug path of application, that enable me to run the application from wherever it is like pen drive or external hard (like a portable application)

Comment: Use `Application.StartupPath`

Comment: May you detailed your answer by comment,please @SriramSakthivel?

Comment: If I understand correctly you need to find exe path. If yes you can read exe path via `Application.StartupPath` property.

Comment: when i use StreamReader fileitem = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "dataset.txt"));     the Application.StartupPath is disactive!!! May you tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

```
string documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
StreamReader fileitem = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(documents, "dataset.txt");
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @mnieto. If I want to change the path the exe path of application. I mean I copy the text files into the .../bin/debug path of application, that enable me to run the application from wherever it is like pen drive or external hard (like a portable application)

Comment: In that case, set a relative path for the document. And, in solution explorer, set the `copy to output directory` property to `Copy if newer`.